# How does this data frame example in the Websocket RFC equal “Hello”?

Tags: http, websocket, utf-8, dataformat

The first example of [Section 5.7 of Websocket Protocol RFC 6455](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6455#section-5.7) reads:

> A single-frame unmasked text message
>
> - 0x81 0x05 0x48 0x65 0x6c 0x6c 0x6f (contains "Hello")

What are the first two octets in this example and why are they there?

Looking up the UTF-8 codes for the last five octets I can see how those bytes would translate to `Hello`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first two octets in this example contain metadata about the data frame and the payload it contains.  The last five octets represent the payload or `Hello`.

The first two octets `0x81 0x05` are hexadecimal representations of two bytes or 16 bits of data.  In binary they translate to: `1000 0001 0000 0101`.

Using the [Data Frame Diagram](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6455#section-5.2) from the RFC you can see what these bits tell us about the data frame.  To summarize:

- **1st bit (FIN)**: indicates this is the final fragment of the message being sent
- **5th-8th bits (opcode)**: the payload is a text message in UTF-8
- **9th-16th bits (payload length)**: the length of the payload is 5